# Can you fly somehow?

Tags: fez

I read somewhere that you could *fly* in the game.

I have collected every 64 cubes without knowing about it.

Is there any clue in the game explaining how to do it? If so, where?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Flying is a cheat/shortcut **built into New Game+** (a mode after finishing the game once).

It's available once you get perspective controls back. **Press ↑↑↑↑ (up 4x) and jump.**

There is no in-game explanation—[it's just something you find](https://twitter.com/#!/Polytron/status/191172580319830017).

A helpful tip: When flying downwards and triggering Gomez's "falling to his death" animation, you can avoid collapsing upon touching land by **jumping** just as you make contact.

Comment: How did you know that?

Comment: @FrançoisCassin Presumably, he's beaten the game and figured it out himself.

Comment: @GnomeSlice Well I have beaten the game too without noticing it was possible. I was just wondering if there were any in-game clues or if he read it elsewhere?

Comment: Ah, well, that's a separate question then, isn't it?  ;)

Comment: To avoid dying from fall damage, you don’t need to jump *just* as you make contact. You just need to be *holding* the jump button when you touch the ground. You can press it long before you hit the ground and you’ll be fine. What’s more, by holding the jump button, you can pass through black holes unhurt if you’re moving fast enough.

Answer (score 3):

I found it by accident as well. Was standing on one of those U shaped pillars (still don't know what they do) and noticed that they looked like a U from all four perspectives. So I hit 'up' four times. Nothing happened, but then I went to jump off the pillar and started flying all over the place!

Comment: I'm sure you've figured this out by now, but the U-shaped pillars are tuning forks, and they are another puzzle.