# Advice on the red lava level

Tags: fez

I'm having a frustrating time on the red lava level in the sewers on Fez. It may be that my platforming skills are not up to par, but are there any suggestions as to how to get through it easier?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The rising lava room's two tricky parts are the turning platforms and the final gauntlet.

- **On the turning platforms**, jump when the platforms are horizontal and pull yourself up fast if you catch its ledge. The platforms will move slightly before turning—this is your indicator to jump up over the center of the platform. You'll land atop the platform when it's vertical. Immediately jump to the next horizontal platform and repeat. This is somewhat nerve-racking as you might catch the next platform's edge as it's about to turn, but it's very doable. And, of course, build up a time/error buffer by speeding through the earlier obstacles (e.g., jump when climbing the nets, and press ↑ at the jump's apex to move faster than just climbing).
- **The final gauntlet, the rising platform**, is a checkpoint—you'll respawn there if you mess up. Don't change the perspective until you're clear of the next horizontal bar. One-third of the way up, one of the sides has a straight shot to the top.

And, yes, you can bypass all the obstacles and [fly](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62687/21177) your way to the top in the New Game+, if you prefer.

Comment: Quick addition: if you are on PC, make sure your keyboard is not ghosting ( https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rollover_(key) ). Mine was, I changed it and that level became WAAAAYYYY easier. In fact, I couldn't finish it with the ghosting keyboard.

Answer (score 3):

The level does not really have a trick; you just have to go through it and climb as fast as possible on the most obvious route. However, once you beat the game once (by collecting 32 cubes) and start a New Game+, you gain the ability to [fly](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62689/1787), which would allow you to easily finish that level without doing any platforming.

Comment: I wish I remembered this before wasting half on hour on those rotating platforms from hell.

Answer (score 1):

I was frustrated over and over again by this level because Fez climbed up the rotating platforms so slowly and by the time he got up, it would often be about to spin and I'd get either thrown off or my jump would be pushed to the side and I couldn't land back on the platform.

Then I figured out that he would climb much faster if I repeatedly tapped up when climbing on the platform.  After that it was much more do-able, because I could actually get on the platform before it would spin.  Hope that helps.

Comment: This is it. I always felt like Fez movement was sluggish unitl I tried tapping up. Not sure why the game behaves like this (and doesn't tell you about it), but hey.