# Is there any way to bypass or cheat through the Lava Level?

Tags: fez

I'm finding this level absolutely impossible. I've been trying for days now to get through it. I can't get past even the first two or three turning platforms.

Is it really this diffucult? It's been such a fun and relaxing game until now – now I really hate this game and i'm just so, so frustrated.

I have seen the answers on "[Advice on the red lava level](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/63810/advice-on-the-red-lava-level)" but it does not quite help enough. Are there any other tips? Any way to cheat it? A way to slow the lava? A way to save the state right at the bottom of the turning platforms? A way to hack my "save state" to say "you finished this level"?!

I'd really just like to hire an expert to get through this level so I can continue with the fun, relaxing exploration that I thought this game was about.

I'm playing on a PC, if that helps.

Answer (score 5):

If you get to the ending and then "restart" with New Game+, you can use the flying code (<kbd>↑</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>+jump) to get through the lava level without opening the valve, and thus complete it at a leisurely pace with very little difficulty.