# How can I tell which part of the game can only be unlocked in New Game+ and which one cannot?

Tags: fez

How can I tell which part of the game can only be unlocked in New Game+ and which one cannot?

I am getting frustrated with this game, not with the complexity of it, but the lack of information on what I am supposed to expect to be able to do in the first playthrough. How should I know that I can't lower the water level till New Game+? What exactly is the goal of the first playthrough? What's the fundamental difference between New Game+ and the first playthrough?

Comment: This doesn't directly answer your question, but my advice would be to skip a puzzle if you can't see any way to solve it. Once you cannot see a clear way to make progress on any puzzle you can access, then worry about this problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idea is **to play through to the 32-cube ending**, which should present itself as a natural progression. Once you finish the game, you have no choice but to start a new game (the New Game+) if you're so inclined to complete every puzzle (or "209.4%" the game). The NG+ is the same as the first playthrough (everything carrries over) except for one [bonus feature](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62436/21177), which only actually helps with one puzzle-type:

> The [white and purple pillars](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62428/21177) (not the U-shaped tuning fork pillars) are the only puzzles that depend on the first-person vision New Game+ bonus.

The rest can be solved without it in the first playthrough. There is no in-game method for telling which puzzles have all of its pieces. It requires unusual attention to hidden/obscure codes and nuances. One could contend that the game's main conceit is withholding information from the player (see [the monolith debacle](http://kotaku.com/monolith-room/)). Later (optional) Easter eggs include finding the 64-cube door and collecting the heart cube pieces. You will most likely check the Internet for answers before exhausting every in-game clue, and, presumably, *Fez* was designed to be played with that in mind.

Comment: The black monolith puzzle you mention would be an example of a puzzle unsolvable on the first play through.  Certain hints would not make sense.  Of course, sort of a moot point in light of the "debacle".

Comment: @EBongo: Real talk. But since the monolith is an Easter egg, I wouldn't consider it part of the game proper

Comment: Would flying be part of the new game+ only feature?

Comment: Yes, [flying](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62687/21177) is a NG+ Easter egg (not introduced as a feature).