# How do I fly down from a high ledge?

Tags: fez

I was stupid and flew to a high ledge in *Fez*, and now I can't get down.

I've been trying to fly/float down slowly, but I get the "You have fallen to your death" sound, and I automatically respawn at the top just before touching the ground. [Someone wrote](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/62689/21177) that I can float down there if I press A just as I'm about to hit the ground, but since I respawn before I can get to the ground, that solution doesn't apply....

Does anyone know of any solution to this? Any secret reset spawn point code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can free-fall (with the "dying" animation) for a few seconds before you're reset up on your high ledge. **Your best bet is moving down successive ledges until you get to your destination.** It will take more time than just jumping down directly, but it's faster than trying and failing multiple times. Some tips:

- I believe I was the one with the jumping tip—even if you're in the "dying" animation, tap **<kbd>A</kbd>** rapidly right before hitting the ground. You'll jump once and not die.
- When falling near green wall vines, press **<kbd>↑</kbd>** to catch them. You can stop your fall this way even if you're in the "dying" animation.
- Float down slowly by holding down **<kbd>A</kbd>** whenever Gomez does the "dying" animation. He'll stop heaving in a few seconds and you can continue downwards. You'll lose some downward progress by floating up, but if you do this a few times on your descent, you'll find you can float all the way down.

There is no secret reset spawn code, as you mentioned. If you reset your game, you'll start the room near the door used to enter it. If you just can't make it down, you can just continue on—the last room node in the chain invariably has a nearby warp portal back to the warp zone.

I can help more specifically if you mention the room you're in.

Answer (score 3):

Try exiting the game and then opening it again. I did that and it loaded me at a lower ledge.