# In Fez, how do I lower to the bottom door without dying?

Tags: fez

I'm outside the observatory (where the telescope room is) and I can't get to the bottom. I got up by way of the grassy flipping squares but I can't take the same way down. Getting to the door at the bottom is the only way I can continue playing but there is no way of lowering without dying. Help! PS I tried resetting, pressing A before landing, etc

Comment: There has to be something that you are over looking. Or some alternate route that you are missing, one that progress's further and then links up with the starting route, the one you originally took to get where you are. Is there water around? You can jump into that without dying, I think.

Comment: The "pressing A before landing" only works [when you fly](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/62687/21177).

Answer (score 4):

### Use the warp door on the side of the octopus building,

[image: warp door]

### OR fall down whence you came, but grab onto the vertical grass to avoid dying.

[image: catch the vertical grass]